# Appcelerator Android app on Kiosk mode (startLockTask)

Tags: android, appcelerator, kiosk-mode

I am looking to create an Android app, which should run itself in Kiosk-mode. I want to build it in Appcelerator. I have found some info on calling startLockTask() in your Activity (https://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-3-android-lollipop) but I am not sure if there is a solution in Appcelerator that is comparable.

Does anybody have any experience in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[@rainer-schleevoigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430513/rainer-schleevoigt) created a Titanium kiosk module for android at:
https://github.com/AppWerft/android-kiosk-mode

Comment: Can you provide information how to use that module?